# Remove Semi-Visible Fire Domain

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

While trying to render some fire simulation, I noticed my domain's volume is semi-visible.

Does anyone know how I can remove this shadow-like box?

[image: 1]]

Edit:

Due to the request on trying to add more information on this question, here is my best explanation.

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctd_09qHacA) on youtube on how to create fire. 
When I render the scene, that blackbox appears and I assume it has the dimensions that the smoke takes due to settings, but I might be wrong.

These are the nodes he used (25:25)
[image: 3]]

My outliner looks like this
[image: 2]]

And these are the dimensions of my domain
[image: 4]]

Hope I made myself a bit clearer

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings.

Comment: @cegaton Edited, not sure if I made myself clear on the question